# Swift: Did select row at index path returns nil when using a static table

Tags: ios, swift

I am building a settings page in my application, it therefore makes sense to use static cells instead of dynamic cells as I never dynamically generate any content within this view.

I have adopted the pattern of splitting the table up into multiple groups for each category i.e. User Preferences, Settings etc.

I tried using `UITableView`s delegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but when debugging I always seem to be getting a null value passed for my cell.  What I need to do is extract the text from a label to depict actions for cells which do not have a segue (such as Logout and Delete Account, these simply present a confirmation modal which will then process the action)

My `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    if cell != nil {
        // Set the CellID
        var cellID: AnyObject! = (cell?.textLabel!.text == nil) ? "" : cell?.textLabel?.text

        // The values are hardcoded so we can switch with confidence
        switch cellID as String {
        case "Logout":
            logout()
        default:
            println("un-managed action \(cellID.localizedDescription) and \(cellID) index path: \(indexPath)")
        }
    }
}
```

Why am I always getting `nil` printed as a result?  My only guess is that it looks for index 0 in all available sections and can't make an assumption as to which cell I am pointing too and therefore returns a `nil` object, some clarification and a solution would be great.

Comment: cell.textLabel should equal nil if you've never specifically set cell's textLabel property... Are you creating these "static" cells in the interface? And your log in didSelectRowAtIndexPath is in fact printing right?

Comment: All properties are hardcoded in the storyboard, shouldn't it inherit those values?

Comment: You've probably added *a* UILabel to the cell. That's not the same as cell.textlabel

Comment: Ack, yes I have.  Do I need to subclass the cell to get access to those values?

Comment: You don't *have* to. You could also loop through the cell's subviews and access the label dynamically.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution, any chance you may be able to provide an example as an answer? Haven't done that before...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is clear in your comments, you've never specifically set your cell's `textLabel` property; you've only added a `UILabel` to your cell in the interface. Assuming you only have one label added to each cell, you can loop through the cell's subviews and access the label dynamically by finding the `UILabel` subview, ex:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    if cell != nil {
        // Set the CellID

        var label:UILabel = UILabel()
        for subview in self.view.subviews {
            if subview is UILabel {
                label = subview as UILabel
                break
            }
        }

        var cellID: AnyObject! = (label.text == nil) ? "" : label.text

        // The values are hardcoded so we can switch with confidence
        switch cellID as String {
        case "Logout":
            logout()
        default:
            println("un-managed action \(cellID.localizedDescription) and \(cellID) index path: \(indexPath)")
        }
    }
}
```

If you have multiple labels in your cell, you can add a tag to each one then check for the tag within the for loop.